# AS3: 3D axes rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, rotation

I've built a 3D icosahedron in AS3 that I'm going to use as a 20-sided die. With rotationX, rotationY, and rotationZ all set to 0, it looks like the top left picture. Now I'm trying to find the proper rotations for each number so that the face is perpendicular to the screen, like in the top right picture for #1. The problem is that when I rotate it one way, the axes of rotation are changed as well. For example, in the bottom left picture when I was trying to do #2, I set rotationZ to 108, but now rotationX will not turn it straight downwards as it did before.

I could just eyeball it and get approximate rotations that looked about right, but I would rather have exact rotations. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I needed to use Matrix3D instead for my rotations.